# Выравнивание виджета в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Здравствуйте.
Продолжая разбираться с графикой, получил следующую проблему, которая относится к выравниванию.
Как осуществить в `Tkinter` выравнивание слева сверху? `topleft` или `TOPLEFT` не существует, пишет сначала `side=top`, потом `side=left`, ругается на повтор `side`'a.
Конкретно мне нужно, чтобы созданный фрейм был в левом верхнем углу окна!

Comment: pack такого не поймёт.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему используя не pack(), а place()

```
insert.place(anchor=NW)
```

Comment: Вообще Shipman в своём Tkinter 8.4 reference: a GUI for Python настоятельно рекомендует пользоваться grid. (Ну ещё из tcl/tk -- нельзя в одном приложении использовать pack и place. Возможно стоит прислушаться к этому совету. Тем более, что шаг сетки по умолчанию неравномерный. И -- читать Tk (не только Tkinter)

Answer (score 1):

```
frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, давайте более развернутые ответы